# Can't .animate() after .ajax() request

Tags: ajax, jquery

I need to animate a div after `.ajax()` success, but it just won't. Before ajax i can, but not after ajax in `.done()` function. Please help, i tried everything.

Here is my code:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
   $this = $(this).closest(".photo");
   var url = $(this).parent().find("input[type=hidden]").val();
        $.ajax({url: '/content/delete.php',
              data: {id: url},
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'post',
        }).done(function( output ) {
           if(output){
             $this.find(".slider").animate({margin: '0px'}, 200);
           }
        });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the ajax callback is called? May `output` is false or the ajax request fail.

Comment: Yes, callback is always true, the image is deleted, only the animation doesn't works.

Comment: Put a `console.log` in there to be sure.

Comment: Can you put `console.log(output);` before `if(output){` and post here what does it output?

Comment: You are of course returning valid JSON from the server, as that is what you are expecting. If you chain a fail() function on there, I'm pretty sure it will be called.

Comment: I put .fail() after .ajax() but it wasn't called.

Comment: place a `console.log(output)` inside the `done()` function, and tell us what you got ?

Comment: What about `$this.find(".slider")`, is it initialised?

Comment: I think yes: [div.slider, prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1], context: button.delete, selector: ".closest(.photo) .slider", constructor: function, init: function…]

Comment: What is the margin of object on the moment done callback is initialised?

Comment: it's -234px before .ajax() is called

Comment: But you've set the dataType to JSON, so anything other than JSON, and the ajax call will fail. That is, the serverside script will do it's thing, but the done function would fail with a parse error, so how you're getting just "true" is beyond me. Did you try removing the dataType option all together.

Comment: @adeneo `"true"`, `true` is valid JSON http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/smgsn/

Comment: @Musa - it's not really valid JSON, but it does'nt seem to trigger a parse error, so that's not the problem. The problem seems to have been using queue() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably had mistake in code before. I used .animate() before .ajax() like this:

```
$this.find(".slider").animate({marginTop: '-234px'}, 200).queue(function() {
    margin = 1;
});
```

So i edit it to:

```
$this.find(".slider").animate({marginTop: '-234px'}, 200, function() {
    margin = 1;
});
```

And it works.